# When can one recover a topological space from all continuous maps from simplices?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm on my first course on algebraic topology, following Munkres's Elements of Algebraic Topology. We've finished the part of simplicial homology and have begined to study singular homology.

For a simplicial complex $K$, we know topology of $K$ is coherent with all simplices of $K$. Here by saying coherent I mean if we equip the simplices of $K$ subspace topology inherited from $K$, and consider the final topology of $K$ induced by the natural inclusion maps of these simplices, then the final topology coincides with the original topology.

Now for any topological space $X$, we define its singular $p$-chain group to be the free abelian group generated by all continuous maps $\Delta^p\to X, p=0, 1, \dotsc$. So a continuous map $\Delta^p\to X$ in singular homology somehow generalizes the notion of a $p$-dimensional simplex of $K$ in simplex homology. Since one can recover the topology of a complex from its simplices, I'm wondering **whether one can reconstruct the topology from all maps $\Delta^p\to X, p=0, 1, \dotsc$**.

For a triangulable space, I think the answer should be yes. Since the final topology of $X$ w.r.t. $\Delta^p\to X$ is finer (not necessarily strictly finer) than original topology of $X$, while the original topology of $X$ is the finest topology that make the inclusion maps of simplices continuous.

From googling I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2698390) which shows that there are certain spaces that is not compactly generated, and hence don't satisfy our condition.

My question is: **Is there any non-triangulable space $X$ whose topology can be reconstructed by $\{\Delta^p\to X: p=0, 1, \dotsc\}$?**

Thank you very mush for any comments.

Comment: I think these are called Delta-generated spaces.

Comment: Consider any non-triangulable CW complex (note that $\Delta^n\cong D^n$). This should convince you that trianguability is not relevant. Now take any generalised CW complex (where the dimensions of the attached cells needs not be ascending) which admits no CW complex structure. Thus there are non CW examples. Of course there are horrendous spaces meeting the requirements. (There are continuous surjection $[0,1]\rightarrow \Delta^n$, so it suffices for the topology of $X$ to be coherent wrt all maps $[0,1]\rightarrow X$.)

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks very much! I'll go back to this once I get familiar with CW complexes. Only one question: How can the existence of surjection $I\to \Delta^n$ imply that it suffices for the topology of $X$ to be coherent w.r.t. all maps $[0, 1]\to X$? Maybe it needs the surjection map to be open or closed?

Comment: @Noto_Ootori, all maps between compact Hausdorff spaces are closed, and every closed surjection is a quotient map.